# How to decode NOTAM?

Tags: airspace, icao, notam

I am not a professional, but an amateur trying to self-learn NOTAM code. I need some help in decoding this real NOTAM:

> A1671/23 - VIDF (India): Temporary restricted area Activated FIR
>
> Period: 2023-08-25T00:00:00.000Z - 2023-08-25T23:59:00.000Z
>
> Q-Code (RTCA): Navigation WarningsAirspace restrictionsTemporary
> restricted areaActivatedChanges
>
> AIRSPACE USE PLAN (AUP) TSA/TRA /AMC-MANAGEABLE AIRSPACE ACT AS FLW :
> NR AIRSPACE ID TIME FM TIME TO LOWER FL UPPER FL 1 TRA503 (A) (PUNE)
> 0230 1030 FL325 FL430 2 TRA503 (B) (PUNE) 0230 1030 FL325 FL430 3
> TRA507 (RATNAGIRI) 0330 0800 GND A065 4 TRA508(A) (SHIKRA) 0200 1200
> GND A007 5 TRA508(A) (SHIKRA) 1330 1730 GND A007 6 TRA508(B) (SHIKRA)
> 0200 1200 GND A015 7 TRA508(B) (SHIKRA) 1330 1730 GND A015 8 TRA508(C)
> (SHIKRA) 0200 1200 GND A030 9 TRA508(C) (SHIKRA) 1330 1730 GND A030 10
> TSA509 (NAVAL DOCKYARD) 0200 1200 GND A015 11 TSA509 (NAVAL DOCKYARD)
> 1330 1730 GND A015 12 TSA701 (A) (ADAMPUR) 0030 1929 FL145 FL280 13
> TSA701 (B) (ADAMPUR) 0030 1929 GND FL280 14 TRA702 (A) (SRINAGAR) 0130
> 1130 FL170 FL310 15 TRA702 (A) (SRINAGAR) 1400 1930 FL170 FL310 16
> TRA702 (B) (SRINAGAR) 0100 1030 GND FL310 17 TRA705 (AMBALA) 0500 0800
> FL325 FL500 18 TRA706 (A) (GWALIOR) 0230 1100 FL325 FL460 19 TRA706
> (B) (GWALIOR) 0230 1100 FL325 FL460 20 TRA706 (C) (GWALIOR) 0230 1100
> FL325 FL460 21 TRA711 (A) (AGRA) 0230 1100 FL325 FL460 22 TRA711 (B)
> (AGRA) 0230 1100 FL325 FL460 23 TRA716 (A) (BAREILLY) 0230 1000 FL325
> FL460 24 TRA716 (B) (BAREILLY) 0230 1000 FL325 FL460 25 TRA716 (C)
> (BAREILLY) 0230 1000 FL325 FL460 26 TSA722 (GRASS BIR - 13) 0330 1130
> GND FL280 PART 1 OF 6 CREATED: 24 Aug 2023 11:33:00 SOURCE: VIDPYNYX

I understand some commonly known abbreviations but what would this mean in plain English?

Comment: Cross-posted here: https://www.reddit.com/r/flying/comments/160psg8/need_help_decoding_this_notam_to_plain_english/

Comment: Yeah trying to find help there too

Comment: Why don't you share with us the parts you already understand so someone doesn't have to spend more time than necessary telling you things you already know.

Comment: Surely there are on-line decoders-- then you could see the whole thing in plain English and your questions would be answered.  I googled "Decode NOTAMS" and got a lot of hits.  https://www.notams.faa.gov/downloads/contractions.pdf may be what you need.  See also https://www.drorpilot.com/English/notam.htm , https://www.thinkaviation.net/notams-decoded/ , https://www.theairlinepilots.com/flightplanningforairlinepilots/notamdecode.php , and many more.  Feel free anyone to make an answer based on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How to decode NOTAM?

Actually this NOTAM is not coded.

The coded version is only used for transfer on the aeronautical fixed service (AFS), a sort of telex network used by aviation entities all over the world. The coded uses only short codes, e.g. `temporary restricted area` is `QRT`.

While it is the plain version, it still uses a lot of identifiers and abbreviations. Let's first format the text into a more readable form:

```
NOTAM A1671/23
VIDF
Temporary restricted area
Activated
FIR
Period: 2023-08-25T00:00:00.000Z - 2023-08-25T23:59:00.000Z

Q-Code (RTCA): 
  Navigation
  Warnings
  Airspace restrictions
  Temporary restricted area
  Activated
  Changes

AIRSPACE USE PLAN (AUP)    
TSA/TRA /AMC-MANAGEABLE AIRSPACE ACT AS FLW :

NR AIRSPACE ID        TIME FM TIME TO LOWER FL UPPER FL
1  TRA503 (A) (PUNE)  0230    1030    FL325    FL430
2  TRA503 (B) (PUNE)  0230    1030    FL325    FL430
3  TRA507 (RATNAGIRI) 0330    0800    GND      A065 
4  TRA508(A) (SHIKRA) 0200

...

PART 1 OF 6
CREATED: 24 Aug 2023 11:33:00
SOURCE: VIDPYNYX
```

**Explanations**

```
NOTAM A1671/23
VIDF
Temporary restricted area
Activated
FIR
Period: 2023-08-25T00:00:00.000Z - 2023-08-25T23:59:00.000Z
```

This is a NOTAM from the [Delhi FIR](https://www.theairlinepilots.com/flightplanningforairlinepilots/decodedicaolocationidentifier/icaofirlist.php), related to the activation of temporary segregated areas or temporary reserved areas (which are in Mumbaï FIR). This is usually to give a specific user the exclusive right to fly in a certain airspace at a certain time. The NOTAM is valid for August 25, 2023.

```
Q-Code (RTCA): 
  Navigation
  Warnings
  Airspace restrictions
  Temporary restricted area
  Activated
  Changes
```

These are categories pertaining to the NOTAM content. They were received as codes, according to [RTCA Q-Codes](https://www.notams.faa.gov/common/qcode/qcode23.html) standard. The meaning is straightforward.

```
AIRSPACE USE PLAN (AUP)
TSA/TRA /AMC-MANAGEABLE AIRSPACE ACT AS FLW :
```

This is about airspace use (AUP), specifically about manageable airspace. India has establish airspace management cells (AMC). The procedures used are described in the AIP in [Manual of flexible use of airspace](https://aim-india.aai.aero/sites/default/files/aip_supplements/AIPS_2017_12.pdf).

The list of areas concerned by this NOTAM is then given, with an indication of the time widows and altitudes which are regulated, e.g.

```
NR  AIRSPACE ID         TIME FM  TIME TO  LOWER FL  UPPER FL
1   TRA503 (A) (PUNE)   0230     1030     FL325     FL430
```

is related to TRA503 (A) which ATC unit is Pune ACC in Mumbai FIR. This reserved area is [defined in the AIP](https://aim-india.aai.aero/sites/default/files/aip_supplements/AIPS_2020_237.pdf), and the controlling authority is the Indian Air Force. This means the military have control of this area, but it can be used under certain conditions by civil flights, and Pune ACC has a delegation for these flights (in practical when the area is active, a civil and a military controller work together).

Note it is said in the AIP "*Activation of TRA will be notified through AUP/UUP by AMC*", and this NOTAM, which is an AUP, is the required notification.

TRA503 (A) is reserved to the controlling authority between 02:30 and 10:30 (on 25 August 2023), between FL325 and FL430.

The other rows are similar.

```
SOURCE: VIDPYNYX
```

This NOTAM was sent on the aeronautical network by the International NOTAM Office of the Airports Authority of India, which code on the network is `VIDPYNYX`.

---

Overall: The NOTAM is the notification for the use of certain areas, which are controlled by the air force, but open to civilians. This shared airspace is regulated, and details are found in the AIP as well as the way they are activated, meaning their access can be restricted. These areas are duly shown on aeronautical maps.

More:

- [How to find out if Restricted Area is "hot" before taking off?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/16573/3201)
- [What are some examples of warning areas and restricted areas?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/20877/3201)
- [Can a pilot fly through a restricted area while flying on a Victor Airway?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/13234/3201)
- [Restricted Area "popping up" around you -- can it happen, and what do you do about it?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/16595/3201)